# Is this integration error from a misuse of Mathematica or is it my poor math skills?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages

I have input this:

```
Integrate[1, f[t]*Exp[(v/V)*t]]
```

That is $\large\int 1*d(f(t)*e^{\frac{v}{V}*t})$

I expected this output:
$\large f(t)*e^{\frac{v}{V}*t} + C$

but instead I get:

```
Integrate::ilim: "Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in E^((t\v)/V)\ f[t]. "
```

What am I doing wrong ?

PS: in the model at the origin of my troubles t is the only variable v and V are constants

Comment: But I want to integrate 1 with respect to f(t)*e^(v/V*t).

Comment: You can want whatever you like, but you have to adhere to the Mathematica syntax. It expects a variable in that position and what you provide is clearly not a variable.

Comment: Integrate[1, u] /. u -> f[t]*Exp[(v/V)*t]

Comment: This works thanks gpap do you want to put it as an answer?

Comment: The type of integral you want to calculate often pops up when using the integration by parts trick. The resulting expression with a function behind the d is considered by many a (slight) abuse of notation and not mathematically solid.

Comment: This comes from using an integrating actor, see my trouble here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455577/how-to-solve-this-simple-ordinary-differential-equation

Comment: Y'all don't be so hard on the new guy.  He formatted his first question very nicely and that earns a +1 in my book by itself.  @gpap agreed; why not post an answer?

Comment: There is an ambiguity-- Which is the variable and which are constants?  It would make a significant difference if instead of `1`, the integrand were not constant, say, `t * v^2 * V^3`.

Comment: I have edited it now, t is the variable in the original equation but according to he book method I needed to integrate in respect to the whole f(t)... See the link I put in the comments above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, here's a (trivial) answer that works:

```
Module[{u}, Integrate[1, u] /. u -> f[t]*Exp[(v/V)*t]]
```

Comment: FYI: For best style `u` should be `\[FormalU]` or localized with `Module`. (+1)

Comment: agreed and amended

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to implement your concept.  But you do have to specify which variable is the variable of integration:

```
SetAttributes[int, HoldAll];
int[integrand_, D[measure_, var_Symbol]] := Integrate[integrand D[measure, var], var]

int[1, D[f[t]*Exp[(v/V)*t], t]]
(* E^((t v)/V) f[t] *)
```

And

```
int[f[t] Exp[(v/V) t], D[f[t]*Exp[(v/V)*t], t]]
(* 1/2 E^((2 t v)/V) f[t]^2 *)
```

Etc.